# Something is crashing my app after I implemented Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, crash, textview, spinner

Just to clarify first, I'm a newbie with Java and Android, and I'm still in a heavy learning process.

Anyway...

I'm working on a simple Parking SMS app, and I'm stuck with Spinner and a TextView.

Basically, I'm trying to do this: when I select a Parking zone from a Spinner (it has five parking zones), I want to populate a Parking zone description to a TextView below Spinner in the Layout.

Spinner has its own StringArray, while Parking zone descriptions are each in its own Strings.

So it looks like this:

activity_glavni.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Glavni">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/txGrad"
                android:id="@+id/txOdaberiteGrad"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnergradovi"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txOdaberiteGrad"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="20px"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:id="@+id/space" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/txZona"
                android:text="@string/txZona"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnergradovi"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerZona"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txZona"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/txPrikazZone"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerZona" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextRegistracija"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txPrikazZone"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Unesite broj registracije" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_posalji"
    android:id="@+id/btn_posalji"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextRegistracija"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    />
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">ParkingZagreb</string>


<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="txGrad">Odaberite grad</string>
<string name="txZona">Odaberite zonu</string>
<string name="btn_posalji">Pošalji SMS!</string>
<string-array name="gradovi">
    <item>Zagreb</item>
    <item>Velika Gorica</item>
    <item>Zaprešić</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="zone">
    <item>Prva zona</item>
    <item>Druga zona</item>
    <item>Treća zona</item>
    <item>Četvrta zona (1)</item>
    <item>Četvrta zona (2)</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="opisi_zona">
    <item>6 kn/h, maksimalno 2 h</item>
    <item>3 kn/h, maksimalno 3 h</item>
    <item>1,5 kn/h, bez ograničenja</item>
    <item>5 kn/dan, 7-16 h</item>
    <item>10 kn/dan, 7-20 h</item>
</string-array>
```

Glavni.java

```
public class Glavni extends ActionBarActivity {

public TextView txPrikazZone;
private Button btn_posalji;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glavni);

    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    btn_posalji = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_posalji);
    btn_posalji.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Glavni.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("SMS poslan!");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Provjerite SMS aplikaciju. Poruka bi trebala doći za nekoliko trenutaka.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });


    // the first city selection Spinner


    Spinner spinner_gradovi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnergradovi);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.gradovi, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_gradovi.setAdapter(adapter);


    // the second Spinner with parking zones

    final Spinner spinner_zona = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerZona);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.zone, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_zona.setAdapter(adapter2);


    // this is where I'm trying to populate the TextView with the String-Array by selecting an item from the second Spinner     

    final String[] opisi_zona = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.opisi_zona);

    spinner_zona.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            txPrikazZone.setText(opisi_zona[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_glavni, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Has `txPrikazZone` been initialized properly?

Comment: @IgorGajic What is on line 89 of Glavni.java?

Comment: @stkent it's set on public.

Comment: @iRuth it's txPrikazZone.setText(zona1);

Comment: Please post the full source that shows where you initialized `txPrikazZone`.

Comment: I edited my initial post. Added the full updated code.

Comment: Please post the xml layout file that has `txPrikazZone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the null pointer is that you have not initialized `txPrikazZone` and you are trying to call `setText`.

You need to initialize it in your `onCreate` method like this:

`txPrikazZone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txPrikazZone);`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh my, the basics... I'm so ashamed of myself haha. Well, as I said, I'm a newbie. Big thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter it´s the same for both Spinners

**EDIT**

First try wrapping your ZonaX strings into a string-array

```
<string-array name="zonas">
     ...
</string-array>
```

And now in the code change the set of the ItemSelectedListener

```
final String[] zonas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.zonas); 

spinner_zona.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        txPrikazZone.setText(zonas[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I just renamed adapter for the second Spinner, and it's still crashing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it won't let me choose "getStringArray". I can only choose "getString", and it doesn't work. I tried getResources too, but no luck. It underlines it and says "Change variable ... to java.lang.String."

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot the getResources() before the getStringArray(), check again my edit.

Comment: Big thanks, but still no luck. It's still crashing. As it appears, it sets an error on "at com.example.igor.parkingzagreb.Glavni$2.onItemSelected(Glavni.java:87)", which is "txPrikazZone.setText(opisi_zona[position]);". I checked TextView in the layout. It's "text" property is empty (since the text should be pulled from the String-Array), width is set to match_parent... I have no idea...

Comment: Check if txPrikazZone is null before set the value.

Comment: I got it worked. Huge thanks for your time Fernando :-)